# Finding the difference between the estimated value and the true value in a reward task

Tags: python, performance, functional-programming

I have this function called error, which estimates value based on previous value and rewards in trials. The difference between the estimated value and true value is then calculated, giving the error. I need to run this code 1000 times with different lists of trials, but currently it runs too slowly. How would I optimize this code?

Additional information: alpha is a parameter. Reward and true_value are lists. Value always starts at 0.5, but I remove this starting number before calculating error

```
def loopfunction(alpha, reward, true_value):
    difference = []
    value = [0.5]
    for index, lr in enumerate(reward):
        value.append(lever_update(alpha, value[-1], reward[index]))
    value.pop(0)
    zip_object = zip(value, true_value)
    for value_i, true_value_i in zip_object:
        difference.append(value_i-true_value)
    absdiff = [abs(number) for number in difference]
    
    return absdiff
```

The lever_update function, which calculates value is here:

```
def lever_update(alpha, value, reward):
   value += alpha * (reward - value) 
return(value)
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using list comprehensions instead of numerous `.append` calls is
   often times faster and more readable.
2. A list of rewards should be called `rewards` instead of `reward`. Same goes for `values` and `true_values`.
3. We don't need to `enumerate` rewards, since we don't need the index itself. We can simply iterate over `rewards`.

   ```
   def loopfunction(alpha, rewards, true_values):

       values = [0.5]
       for reward in rewards:
           values.append(lever_update(alpha, values[-1], reward))

       values.pop(0)

       return [abs(value - true_value) for value, true_value in zip(values, true_values)]
   ```

I sadly can't test performance right now, but I would assume the first `for` loop takes up most of your runtime. This is what I'd focus on for further improvements. In general, making code more concise and readable also allows for easier refactoring / performance improvements in the future.

---

We can also make `lever_update` more concise:

```
def lever_update(alpha, value, reward):
   return value + alpha * (reward - value)
```